# Instantiating classes using new

Tags: c++

comming from other programming language why can't I do this in c++:

```
myClass mc = new myClass();
```

it seems that it suffices to just write:

```
myClass mc;
```

but then what if I want to use make mc be a new instance of myClass and dump the existing one?

Comment: What C++ textbook are you learning from that doesn't explain this?

Comment: @NeilButterworth. Your comment nailed it so well that I deleted my attempt to explain :)

Comment: @Neil - none, i think that's the problem.

Comment: @Behrooz You are unlikely to learn C++ properly from internet resources alone. Certainly not simply by asking questions on SO.

Comment: Different languages are - well, different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> comming from other programming language why can't I do this in c++:

Because in C++ to initilize variable types on the left and right side of `=` must be compatible. In your case:

```
myClass mc = new myClass();
```

`mc` has type `myClass` and expression on the right has type `myClass *`. So you either need to change left side to:

```
myClass *mc = new myClass();
```

or right side to:

```
myClass mc = myClass();
```

to make both sides compatible. What implications it would have on class instance lifetime you should get from a C++ textbook.

Comment: Thanks for you clear explanation. It solved my immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

`new` generates the object using dynamic memory from the heap. Your second line allocates it on the stack or in the data section. Please read about the differences of stack, heap and data section and the consequences for your application!

Comment: There is no such thing as stack or heap in C++

Comment: @Slava so where do you get your memory from?

Comment: I buy them on amazon

Comment: I do not know if the C++ standard mentions amazon...

Comment: @koalo He's referring to the fact that the C++ standard doesn't use stack/heap terminology with regards to memory.  The difference in these situations is _memory storage duration_, not _memory storage location_ like stack/heap implies.

Comment: It does not mention stack/heap either (in this meaning, it does mention containers of that names)

Comment: I got that ;-) I just noticed that many people can understand the concept of location better than the concept of lifetime and it is an important information while debugging, so I prefer these terms even if there could be a system that will handle those differently (if just by overloading new and implementing custom memory management, been there...)

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword means allocating heap memory to a pointer

```
int* pointer = new int(5);
```

This means that the int will be allocated on the heap as opposed to the stack.

When allocating memory with the `new` keyword you also have to `delete` it

```
delete pointer;
```

In your case, you should be able to assign a new value like so

```
mc = myClass();
```

without the `new` keyword.

Comment: "To assign a new value to a non-pointer you can just do `mc = myClass();`" You _may_ be able to do that, depending on what operators the class supports, but there is no guarantee that you can do so in all (or even most) cases.

Comment: There's a lot of other information Behrooz probably needs, but this answer nicely summarises what's worth trying to keep stumbling along, until the textbook Neil advocates materialises.